# Node.js - Page times out - Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am running a node.js app using mongoose, express, mongodb. I have a 'team' page which displays a list of teams in a database at the moment, it worked previously absolutely fine, but since I have added in the code below....I can navigate to the pge and view it, and after that if I refresh the page or try to load the team page once more, the page times out and does not load, yet in the terminal it does show `GET /team`

Here is the code I have added in:

routes/index.js

```
var getAllMeta = function(req, res, next){
  Team.getAllMeta(function(err, teamsList){
    if(!err && teamsList){
      req.teamsList = teamsList;
    }
    next(err);
  });
};

  app.get('/team', getAllMeta, function(req, res){
    util.log('Serving request for url[GET] ' + req.route.path);
    if(req.session.user){
      res.render('team', {'teamsList' : req.teamsList} );
    } else {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  });
```

The HTML code is .jade which simply includes the following code to use the teamsList to display the teams:

```
div#teamListDiv
  -if(teamsList.length > 0){
    -each team in teamsList
      a.teamLink(id="#{team.key}", href="#") #{team.name}
      br
  -}else{
    h3 No teams till now..
  -}
```

So it works perfectly fine, but once refreshed or reloaded, it times out and does nothing. Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: After letting it load, here is the error code at the terminal

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:645:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (/Users/sweetest_viv/nodeapps/tournamentManager/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:59:22)
    at next (/Users/sweetest_viv/nodeapps/tournamentManager/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:162:13)
    at pass (/Users/sweetest_viv/nodeapps/tournamentManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:107:24)
    at nextRoute (/Users/sweetest_viv/nodeapps/tournamentManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:100:7)
    at callbacks (/Users/sweetest_viv/nodeapps/tournamentManager/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:11)
    at Promise.getAllMeta (/Users/sweetest_viv/nodeapps/tournamentManager/routes/index.js:17:5)
    at Promise.addBack (/Users/sweetest_viv/nodeapps/tournamentManager/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:128:8)
    at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at Promise.emit (/Users/sweetest_viv/nodeapps/tournamentManager/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:66:38)
```

The code at line 17 of index.js is

```
next(err);
```

which is in the getAllMeta function I posted above

EDIT 2: Team.getAllMeta

```
Team.statics.getAllMeta = function(cb){
  var query = this.find({}, 'key name', cb);
  return query.exec(cb);
};
```

Comment: It sounds like `Team.getAllMeta` is calling its callback multiple times.  What does that method look like?

Comment: @AaronDufour I have added the `getAllMeta` method to the bottom of the original post for you.

Comment: The fact that you're passing `cb` in two places in Team.getAllMeta is worrying.  Does it work if you take out the line `return query.exec(cb);`?

Comment: `Team.statics.getAllMeta = function(cb){
  return this.find({}, 'key name', cb);
};` I now have this and it works, is that less worrying for you?

Comment: Yeah, I thought that would fix it.  I submitted it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `Team.getAllMeta`:

```
Team.statics.getAllMeta = function(cb){
  var query = this.find({}, 'key name', cb);
  return query.exec(cb);
};
```

Notice how you've passed `cb` multiple times.  It is getting called multiple times, the second time with an error.  Thus, your line `next(err);` fires twice.  The first time, it does what you want it to.  The second time, `err` is non-null and it goes to the default error-handler, which tries to build a response about the error, but fails because the headers have already been sent, and you can't do that twice.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your middleware

```
var getAllMeta = function(req, res, next){
  Team.getAllMeta(function(err, teamsList){
    if(!err && teamsList){
      req.teamsList = teamsList;
    }
    next(err);
  });
};
```

`next(err)` is called **every** time. Even if there is no error. Express forwards the error to the errorHandler and at the same time you're trying to render your page at the `/team` route. Therefore the error `Can't set headers after they are sent`.

Put the following inside your `if () {}` statement

```
return next();
```

That prevents calling `next(err)`.

Comment: so you are saying to make the following inside `Team.getAllMeta`....    `if(!err && teamsList){
      req.teamsList = teamsList;
      return next();
    }` and that's it? I am not returning the `err` then anywhere am I?

Comment: yeah that's right. only pass on the error if it really exists. If the error exists move on to the errorHandler.

Comment: This is not a problem, though, because when `err` is `null`, `next(err)` is treated as not passing an error.  So this change doesn't actually affect the code's behavior.

Comment: yeah that's right. It would cleaner though to add a second `next()` call without the error object.

Comment: That's debatable.  I think its clear and that extra lines of code do more harm than good in this case.  My main point is that this doesn't actually answer the question about the bug OP was experiencing.